# bug in perl with prefixed 0 numbers

Tags: perl

when I try to execute the following`(01434.210 instead of 1434.210)`

```
$val=22749.220-(21315.010+01434.210)
print $val
```

I get these output

```
output 638.207900000001
```

But according to me output must be `0`.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's almost never a bug in Perl. ;)

Comment: In many languages, a prefix 0 makes the number octal; meaning in base 8. I wouldn't be surprised if that's the case here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yep.

Comment: @carcigenicate adding more to your question perl 5.22.1 

$val=0000001;
for(0..10)
{
$val++;
print $val+1;
print "\n";
}     i get desired output

Comment: See also https://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html , which explains the various number formats in Perl.

Comment: @Corion Because any octal number less than 8 is the same in base 10 as it is in base 8. `07` is the same as `7`, but `09` isn't the same as `9`. Same how `1` is the same in both binary and base 10.

Comment: more questions Why there is output difference in these.                           
$val=sprintf("%05d",1434);
print $val;
print "\n";
print $val+21315;
print "\n";
print 01434+21315;

Comment: @Gokul Perl only interprets leading zeroes when reading Perl source code. Addition of scalars is not influenced by that.

Answer (score 13):

A leading 0 in a literal number makes Perl interpret the value I'm base 8:

```
 123   # 123, in decimal
0123   # 123 in octal, but 83 in decimal
```

This isn't the same for strings converted to numbers. In those Perl ignores the leading 0s. The string-to-number conversion only deals in base-10:

```
 "123" + 0   # 123
"0123" + 0   # still 123
```

In your example in the comment, you convert a literal number to a string with a leading zero. When you convert that string back to its numeric form you get the same value you started with:

```
$val=sprintf("%05d",1434);   # converting 1434 to the string "01434"
print $val; print "\n";      # still a string
print $val+21315;            # "01434" + 21315 => 1434 + 21315
print "\n"; 
print 01434+21315;           # oct(1434) + 21315 => 796 + 21315
```

The leading zero notation helps with certain builtins that typically use octal numbers, such as those that deal with unix permissions:

```
chmod 0644, @files
```